# I'm trying to get Tor to run through a proxy

Tags: tor

I want tor to actually run but it tries to setup the built-in proxy against the one that's on my computer. I can't uninstall the one on my computer, but I was wondering how I change the proxy port so it stops trying to go through the previous proxy. It wants me to find the username and password of the proxy that's on my computer, instead of it using the one built in. If this can be done, how to I change the Tor proxy to go through a different route/ip or whatever it needs?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Chrome

Go to options

[image: then]

Then under "Advanced settings" you will find the option to change proxy settings

[image]

then Go to Lan settings in internet options
[image]

check the "use a proxy...." but do not enter anything here
[image]

Instead click advanced
then under "socks"

### enter the following

```
Proxy address:localhost
port :9050
```

Leave other fields empty and apply the settings(click ok on all)

Then enter